# What does it mean to unpack in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

example:

```
var1, var2, var3 = argv
```

unpacks the `argv[]` list

Looked up on google and the Python 2.7 documentation but can't find related answers to my question.

Answer (score 1):

This is called sequence unpacking, and is mentioned at the end of [section 5.3 of the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences):

> The statement `t = 12345, 54321, 'hello!'` is an example of tuple
>   packing: the values `12345`, `54321` and `'hello!'` are packed together in a
>   tuple. The reverse operation is also possible:
>
> ```
> >>> x, y, z = t
> ```
>
> This is called, appropriately enough, *sequence unpacking* and works for any sequence on the right-hand side. Sequence
>   unpacking requires that there are as many variables on the left side
>   of the equals sign as there are elements in the sequence. Note that
>   multiple assignment is really just a combination of tuple packing and
>   sequence unpacking.

Answer (score 1):

Unpacking by using:

```
var1, var2, var3 = argv
```

Is the equivalent of doing:

```
var1 = argv[0]
var2 = argv[1]
var3 = argv[2]
```

The difference is that the unpacking will fail if argv has more (or fewer) items than the number of variables you are giving (I assumed argv contains only 3 elements for the example).

Comment: Thank you! I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

Contratry to the answers

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/55595208/7505395
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/55595170/7505395

you do not need to have the correct amount of params on the left side, you can have less if you specify one to "take the rest" - called ["Extended Iterable Unpacking"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/):

```
k, l, *i, x = range(20)

print(k) 
print(l) 
print(i)  # *i catches all hat are not otherwise matched
print(x)
```

Output:

```
0                                                              # k
1                                                              # l
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]   # *i
19                                                             # x
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, if you have a list, tuple or other iterable, you can assign the separate items in that to the variables on the left.

For example:

```
>>> mylist = [1, 2, 3]
>>> one, two, three = mylist
>>> one
1
>>> two
2
>>> three
3
```

The variables on the left of the assignment now contain the items in the iterable on the right. This does require you to have the correct number of variables on the left to put the items from the iterable on the right into.

This comes in very handy in loops:

```
>>> data = [("filename1.txt", 1024),
>>>         ("filename2.txt", 2048),
>>>         ("filename3.txt", 512)]
>>> for name, size in data:
>>>    print(name, "is", size, "bytes")
filename1.txt is 1024 bytes
filename2.txt is 2048 bytes
filename3.txt is 512 bytes
```

What happens here is that for each item in the data variable, the separate items (the string and the int) are unpacked into the variables `name` and `size` for each run of the `for` loop.

In your specific case, `argv` contains the arguments that you passed if you run your script from the command line. You can unpack the arguments into variables, which is what you did in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Unpack will assign the different values of the right argument inside the different left arguments.
So if you have `a=[0,1,2]` you can unpack it doing: `a0,a1,a2 = a`. As a result `a0` will be equal to `a[0]`, `a1` to `a[1]` etc.

Hope it helps!