# File operations - filtering data from txt file in python

Tags: python

This code works fine but is too big, i would like to know if there is any other way to write this code to make it shorter.

```
 import openpyxl as excel
PATH = "/home/Fathima/workspace/training/"
ACCESS_LIST = []
def READ_CONFIG():
    FROM_ZONE = ""
    TO_ZONE = ""
    POLICY_NAME = ""
    SOURCE_ADDR = ""
    DESTINATION_ADDR = ""
    PORT = ""
    global PATH
    global ACCESS_LIST
    count = 0
    CONFIG_PATH=PATH+"hofwdcn05dcn_20210216(2).txt"
    fh = open(CONFIG_PATH, 'r')
    CONFIG_LINES=fh.readlines()
    config_lines_cnt = len(CONFIG_LINES)
    while count < config_lines_cnt:
        line = CONFIG_LINES[count].strip()
        if len(line) > 0:
            line_to_array = line.split(' ')
            if line.startswith('from-zone '):
                FROM_ZONE = line_to_array[1]
                TO_ZONE = line_to_array[3]
            elif line.startswith('policy '):
                POLICY_NAME = line_to_array[1]
            elif line.startswith('source-address '):
                SOURCE_ADDR = line_to_array[1].replace(";", "")
            elif line.startswith('destination-address '):
                DESTINATION_ADDR = line_to_array[1].replace(";", "")
            elif line.startswith('application '):
                PORT = line_to_array[1].replace(";", "")
            elif line.startswith('then {'):
                count = count+1
                line = CONFIG_LINES[count].strip()
                if line == "permit;":
                    dummy = { 'FROM_ZONE' : FROM_ZONE,'TO_ZONE' : TO_ZONE,'POLICY_NAME' : POLICY_NAME,'SOURCE_ADDR' : SOURCE_ADDR,'DESTINATION_ADDR' : DESTINATION_ADDR,'PORT' : PORT}
                    ACCESS_LIST.append(dummy)
                    FROM_ZONE = ""
                    TO_ZONE = ""
                    POLICY_NAME = ""
                    SOURCE_ADDR = ""
                    DESTINATION_ADDR = ""
                    PORT = ""
        count +=1
#MAIN PROGRAM STARTS FROM HERE
READ_CONFIG()
print(ACCESS_LIST)
```

Here i have a huge file and need the output appearing as below format

[{
from-zone:
to-zone:
policy:
source-address:
destination-address:
application:
},{
from-zone:
to-zone:
policy:
source-address:
destination-address:
application:
}]

Comment: You're missing indentations for all blocks i.e. functions, while loops, conditionals.  this makes it difficult to follow the program flow.

Comment: I have edited the code, please check now, Thanks in advance @DarrylG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a separate related site for a review of working code i.e. [StackExchange Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

That said, below is a more Pythonic code flow.  I didn't change conditionals since they are easy to follow.

Main Changes

- Eliminate globals (discouraged--only for special needs)
- Use file context manager (i.e. use 'with block' on file open)
- Iterate through file rather than read the entire file (allows processing arbitrary file size)
- Use Python variable and function naming convention i.e. [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)
- Remove import openpyxl (unused)

**Code**

```
def read_config(path):

    from_zone, to_zone, policy_name, source_addr, destination_addr, port = [''] * 6
    access_list = []

    with open(path + "hofwdcn05dcn_20210216(2).txt", 'r') as fh:
        for line in fh:
            line = line.strip()
            if line:
                line_to_array = line.split(' ')

                if line.startswith('from-zone '):
                    from_zone = line_to_array[1]
                    to_zone = line_to_array[3]
                elif line.startswith('policy '):
                    policy_name = line_to_array[1]
                elif line.startswith('source-address '):
                    source_addr = line_to_array[1].replace(";", "")
                elif line.startswith('destination-address '):
                    destination_addr = line_to_array[1].replace(";", "")
                elif line.startswith('application '):
                    port = line_to_array[1].replace(";", "")
                elif line.startswith('then {'):
                    line = next(fh).strip()  # Gets next line in file
                    if line == "permit;":
                        access_list.append({'FROM_ZONE': from_zone,
                                            'TO_ZONE': to_zone,
                                            'POLICY_NAME': policy_name,
                                            'SOURCE_ADDR': source_addr,
                                            'DESTINATION_ADDR': destination_addr,
                                            'PORT': port})

                        from_zone, to_zone, policy_name, source_addr, destination_addr, port = [''] * 6
    return access_list

access_list = read_config("/home/Fathima/workspace/training/")
print(access_list)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, works like a pro with minimal coding

Comment: Done, i would like to know why are we multiplying with 6 in the code

Comment: @Tahera--those two instances are using [unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55595010/what-does-it-mean-to-unpack-in-python) of a replicated list i.e.  [replicating elements in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276138/replicating-elements-in-list).  `[''] * 6` creates a list of 6 empty strings i.e. `['', '', '', '', '', '']`, whose elements are unpacked into the variables `from_zone, to_zone, ` etc.  Does this help?

Comment: There's similar type of solution I'm seeking for another txt file, https://stackoverflow.com/q/66655050/15398942 please check if you can help @DarryIG