# Finding data from text file and displaying result in json format

Tags: python

There's a txt file and i need to fetch values under security , firewall, capture only rule number, source, destination port and protocol, if any of the keys are missing need to print default text as 'any' against keys without values, likewise need to get data for said keys in a file

### Txt file data

---

```
security {
    firewall {
        global-state-policy {
            icmp
            tcp
            udp
        }
        name Local {
            default-action drop
            default-log
            description "Local firewall rules."
            rule 9 {
                action accept
                source {
                    address AccountFront
                }
            }
            rule 10 {
                action accept
                source {
                    address SoftLayerBack
                }
            }
            rule 11 {
                action accept
                source {
                    address SoftLayerFront
                }
            }
            rule 20 {
                action accept
                description "Allow ping reply"
                icmp {
                    type 0
                }
               ------
               ------etc
```

Need the output in this form,

```
RULE_NAME{
     9
        SOURCE - 'any' if value doesn't exists
        DESTINAION
        PORT
        POROTCOL
    10
        SOURCE
        DESTINAION
        PORT
        POROTCOL
    11
        ....
}
```

I wrote the below code but it returns empty list.
Please help

```
    name, rule, address, destination, port, protocol= [''] * 6
    access_list = []

    with open(path + "mci_vyatta_config.txt", 'r') as fh:
        for line in fh:
            line = line.strip()
            if line:
                line_to_array = line.split(' ')
            if line == "firewall;":
                if line.startswith('name '):
                    name = line_to_array[1]
                    print(name)
                    #to_zone = line_to_array[3]
                elif line.startswith('rule '):
                    rule = line_to_array[1]
                elif line.startswith('address '):
                    address = line_to_array[1].replace(";", "")
                elif line.startswith('destination '):
                    destination = line_to_array[1].replace(";", "")
                elif line.startswith('port '):
                    port = line_to_array[1].replace(";", "")
                elif line.startswith('protocol '):
                    port = line_to_array[1].replace(";", "")
                elif line.startswith('then {'):
                    line = next(fh).strip()  # Gets next line in file
                    access_list.append({'NAME': name,
                                            'RULE': rule,
                                            'SOURCE': address,
                                            'DESTINATION': destination,
                                            'PORT': port,
                                            'PROTOCOL': protocol})

                    name, rule, address, destination, port, protocol= [''] * 6
    return access_list

access_list = read_config("/home/Fathima/workspace/training/")
print(access_list)
```

---

Some rules has only source ie address and some just has port or protocol, we need to print values if  source, destination port and protocol values exists else need to display keyword as 'any'

```
rule 53 {
                action accept
                description "Allow inbound to Zabbix agent"
                protocol tcp
                source {
                    port ZBX_TCP
                }
                state enable
            }
            rule 60 {
                action accept
                description "Allow UDP ports from VPN peers"
                destination {
                    port IPSecPorts
                }
                protocol udp
                source {
                    address IPSecPeers
                }
            }
```

example - for rule 53, name should be printed just as 53 as rule name, protocol value should be printed as tcp, port as ZBX_TCP and since no address is mentioned it should print 'any'

Comment: @Tahera--In your example text file how are we to associate source, destination port and protocol information with a rule?  For instance, rule 9 has   `{ action accept source { address AccountFront}`  Also in your code you are missing the function definition line.

Comment: Func def is added in my original code, missed to post it here

Comment: Have added last section explaining the same , please check, thanks @DarrylG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a start.

**Code**

```
import re

def parser(filenm):
    '''
        Parser file containing network configuration information
    '''
    rule_block = re.compile(r'\s*rule (?P<rule_number>\d+)\s+\{')  # Line starts a rule block
    address_block = re.compile(r'\s*(?P<address>\w+)\s+\{')    # Start of address info block
    end_block = re.compile(r'\s*\}')              # End block
    
    with open(filenm, 'r') as file:
        stack = []
        bracket_count = 0
        
        for line in file:
            line = line.strip()     # Removes leading/trailing whitespace in line which doesn't matter
            
            if line:                # Process only non-blank lines
                if (m:=rule_block.match(line)):    # Detected Start a new rule
                    bracket_count += 1             # Update Open bracket count
                    nested_type = None
                    
                    # New Dictionary with rule information
                    stack.append({"Rule": m.group('rule_number'), 
                                  "SOURCE": "ANY",
                                  "DESTINATION": "ANY",
                                  "PROTOCOL": "ANY"})   # Start new addresses

                    while (line:=next(file, "").strip()):  # Gets next line in file
                        
                        if end_block.match(line):  # Reached ending block indicator
                            bracket_count -= 1     # Update Close bracket count (i.e. close block)

                            if bracket_count == 0:
                                nested_type = None
                                break              # Done with current rule
                            else:
                                continue

                        if (m:=address_block.match(line)): # Address block in rule
                            nested_type = m.group('address')
                            bracket_count += 1
                            continue

                        data = line.split(maxsplit=1)
                        if len(data) != 2:
                            continue  # skip since has incorrect number of words

                        # Ignore data lines unrelated to desired info
                        if not data[0] in ['action', 'description', 'state']:
                            addresses = stack[-1]
                            if nested_type and data[0].upper()=="ADDRESS":
                                addresses[nested_type.upper()] = data[1]
                            elif nested_type and not nested_type in ['source', 'destination', 'protocol']:
                                addresses['PROTOCOL'] = f"{nested_type.upper()} {' '.join(data)}"
                            else:
                                addresses[data[0].upper()] = data[1]
                
                
    return stack      
   
def display(info):
    '''
        Displays the parsing results
    '''
    print('RULE_NAME {')
    for data in info:
        print(f'\t{data["Rule"]}')
        for k, v in data.items():
            if not "Rule" in k:
                print(f'\t\t{k} {v}')
    print('}')
```

**Usage**

```
results = parser('ip_rules.txt')
display(results)
```

**Input File** ip_rules.txt

```
security {
    firewall {
        global-state-policy {
            icmp
            tcp
            udp
        }
        name Local {
            default-action drop
            default-log
            description "Local firewall rules."
            rule 9 {
                action accept
                source {
                    address AccountFront
                }
            }
            rule 10 {
                action accept
                source {
                    address SoftLayerBack
                }
            }
            rule 11 {
                action accept
                source {
                    address SoftLayerFront
                }
            }
            rule 20 {
                action accept
                description "Allow ping reply"
                icmp {
                    type 0
                }
           }
           rule 53 {
                action accept
                description "Allow inbound to Zabbix agent"
                protocol tcp
                source {
                    port ZBX_TCP
                }
                state enable
            }
            rule 60 {
                action accept
                description "Allow UDP ports from VPN peers"
                destination {
                    port IPSecPorts
                }
                protocol udp
                source {
                    address IPSecPeers
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
RULE_NAME {
    9
        SOURCE AccountFront
        DESTINATION ANY
        PROTOCOL ANY
    10
        SOURCE SoftLayerBack
        DESTINATION ANY
        PROTOCOL ANY
    11
        SOURCE SoftLayerFront
        DESTINATION ANY
        PROTOCOL ANY
    20
        SOURCE ANY
        DESTINATION ANY
        PROTOCOL ICMP type 0
    53
        SOURCE ANY
        DESTINATION ANY
        PROTOCOL tcp
        PORT ZBX_TCP
    60
        SOURCE IPSecPeers
        DESTINATION ANY
        PROTOCOL udp
        PORT IPSecPorts
}
```

**Python 3.6 Compatiable Version**

Doesn't use Walrus operator

```
import re

def parser(filenm):
    '''
        Parser file containing network configuration information
    '''
    rule_block = re.compile(r'\s*rule (?P<rule_number>\d+)\s+\{')  # Line starts a rule block
    address_block = re.compile(r'\s*(?P<address>\w+)\s+\{')    # Start of address info block
    end_block = re.compile(r'\s*\}')              # End block
    
    with open(filenm, 'r') as file:
        stack = []
        bracket_count = 0
        
        for line in file:
            line = line.strip()     # Removes leading/trailing whitespace in line which doesn't matter
            
            if line:                # Process only non-blank lines
                m = rule_block.match(line)
                if m:    # Detected Start a new rule
                    bracket_count += 1             # Update Open bracket count
                    nested_type = None
                    
                    # New Dictionary with rule information
                    stack.append({"Rule": m.group('rule_number'), 
                                  "SOURCE": "ANY",
                                  "DESTINATION": "ANY",
                                  "PROTOCOL": "ANY"})   # Start new addresses
                    
                    line = next(file, "").strip()
                    while line:
                        if end_block.match(line):  # Reached ending block indicator
                            bracket_count -= 1     # Update Close bracket count (i.e. close block)

                            if bracket_count == 0:
                                nested_type = None
                                break              # Done with current rule
                            else:
                                line = next(file, "").strip()  # Gets next line in file
                                continue

                        m = address_block.match(line)
                        if m: # Address block in rule
                            nested_type = m.group('address')
                            bracket_count += 1
                            line = next(file, "").strip()  # Gets next line in file
                            continue

                        data = line.split(maxsplit=1)
                        if len(data) != 2:
                            line = next(file, "").strip()  # Gets next line in file since current line has incorrect number of words
                            continue

                        # Ignore data lines unrelated to desired info
                        if not data[0] in ['action', 'description', 'state']:
                            addresses = stack[-1]
                            if nested_type and data[0].upper()=="ADDRESS":
                                addresses[nested_type.upper()] = data[1]
                            elif nested_type and not nested_type in ['source', 'destination', 'protocol']:
                                addresses['PROTOCOL'] = f"{nested_type.upper()} {' '.join(data)}"
                            else:
                                addresses[data[0].upper()] = data[1]
                              
                            break
                            
                        line = next(file, "").strip()  # Gets next line in file
                
                
    return stack          
        
def display(info):
    '''
        Displays the parsing results
    '''
    print('RULE_NAME {')
    for data in info:
        print(f'\t{data["Rule"]}')
        for k, v in data.items():
            if not "Rule" in k:
                print(f'\t\t{k} {v}')
    print('}')
    
results = parser('ip_rules.txt')
display(results)
```

Comment: Hi Darry, appreciate your efforts but getting following error on running the code
File "rule_task1.py", line 19
    if(m:=rule_block.match(line)):    # Detected Start a new rule
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax 

Will it also work if it has to extract data from huge text file with n rules?

Comment: @Tahera--first the syntax error--are you using Python 3.8+ (which introduced the Walrus operator)?  If not I will have to slightly change the code.

Comment: Python 3.6.8 - this is the version I'm using at present

Comment: @Tahera--I'll add a version that should be compatible with 3.6.  Should just take a few minutes.

Comment: Sure, please take your time :)

Comment: @Tahera--added a 3.6 compatible version.  Notice the difference in the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229995/discussion-between-darrylg-and-tahera).